# How to debug a stored procedure that won't build in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 Create or replace function get_empsalary_by dept(emp_dept varchar(20))
     return number is 
     Total_salary number(10,2);
     emp_dept varchar(20);
     emp_salary number(10,2);
     begin
      select empdept, sum(empsalary) into emp_dept,emp_salary from employe where    empdept=emp_dept;
     total_salary :=sum(empsalary);
     return total_salary;
     end;
    /
```

And the error is:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DEPT" when expecting one of
 the following:
 ( return compress compiled wrapped
```

Comment: Is the table you're trying to read named `employe` or `employee`?

Comment: Pro tip: we like useful and informative titles here. `Can anyone please check this code and help me out` might be appropriate for all 12.7M questions on the site, and thus could do with being more specific. This may have been where you acquired some downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
Create or replace function get_empsalary_by_dept(p_emp_dept in employe.empdept%type)
return number 
is 
  Total_salary number(10,2);
  emp_dept varchar(20);
  emp_salary number(10,2);

begin

  select empdept, sum(empsalary) 
  into emp_dept,emp_salary 
  from employe 
  where    empdept=p_emp_dept
  group by empdept;

  -- total_salary := emp_salary;

  return emp_salary;
end;
/
```

Maybe that this can help you any further.

The name of your function cannot contain any spaces. The input parameter (emp_dept) can not be the same as a variable. The variable emp_dept you do not need in this case. The return value can be emp_salary.

Comment: I can't test it,  but shouldn't the query have  a `group by empdept` (or the empdept field should be removed from the select clause)

Comment: @Insac: You are right. The select statement is missing the group by clause. I have it already added to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called "get_empsalary_by dept" (there is a space between "by" and "dept") and so the parser complains because it expects after function a valid (i.e. without spaces) function name: instead it finds  two strings.

Comment: Hi, I have corrected the typo mistake but it is showing the same error

Comment: Please, correct also the question code. Is it really the same error? Or it is complaining of some other symbol different from "DEPT"? If the latter, please update the error message too.. However, there is also a wrong declaration of emp_dept (it is already the input parameter, so no need to declare it), the select should say only `sum(emp_salary) into total_salary ` (no need for the empdept and emp_salary fields in the select clause) and you should delete the `total_salary := sum(empsalary) ;` row. Ah.. Probably the table name is "employees" and not "employe".